# No Colours in Specflow Feature Files on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, specflow, gherkin

I have the latest version of SpecFlow installed, and still the feature files display uncoloured, like so...

[image: Specflow uncoloured feature files]

Is there certain configurations that are set for colours to be displayed in Specflow files?

VS2015
Specflow 2.1

Comment: Really poor "question". What have you tried so far? Have you tied [any of these](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Troubleshooting-Visual-Studio-Integration)?

Comment: @Reniuz, seems to be certain issues, can't reproduce the solution since it doesn't appear in Options strangely enough

Comment: @RenatasM. can you update your comment spelling mistake.  "Have you TIED". It won't let me edit it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an option for coloring syntax in **Tools->Options->SpecFlow** that could cause the problem.

[image]

EDIT:

Ensure your SpecFlow extension is installed correctly:

Go to **Tools->Extensions and updates -> Installed** look for SpecFlow for *Visual Studio 2015*. You might try to uninstall and install it again.

If you can't find in the list then select **Online**, in search type specflow, then select result and install.

Comment: @Renuiz, as mentioned in the replied comment, specflow doesn't come up under options for me, even though it is installed :/

Comment: Then Extensions and Updates -> uninstall clean temp, restart VS or even PC and install again. I can't dig in your pc configuration so it's hard to say what's wrong :)

Comment: @Renuiz, no option to uninstall clean temp :/ on my version of VS2015 https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdOmv.png

Comment: Tools->Extensions and updates -> Installed look for SpecFlow for Visual Studio 2015

Comment: If you can't find in the list then select `Online`, in search type specflow, then select result and install.

Answer (score 4):

Gherkin code highlighting issue on Visual Studio 2019

For Visual studio 2019 need to install an Extension 
Extensions -> Manage Extensions -> Search for Specflow

Can see Extension by name 'Specflow for Visual Studio 2019' click and restart the Visual Studio 2019 app.

Answer (score 4):

FIX for VS 2022

If this is still an issue, On update, the extension is removed.

Navigate to Extensions, Click Online, Search Specflow and install the extension.

Restart and modify

Fix is complete

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the coloring in some projects but in other I haven't. Pre-installing the Visual Studio extension worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

**Disable Conflicting Extensions**

Sometimes, other extensions can conflict with Gherkin syntax highlighting:

Go to the 'Extensions' menu and click on 'Manage Extensions'.

Look through your installed extensions for any that might interfere with Gherkin or SpecFlow.

Disable these extensions one by one, restarting Visual Studio each time to check if the issue is resolved.

**Method 2:**

Check Your Visual Studio Settings

Visual Studio's settings related to text editors and language services could affect syntax highlighting:

Go to 'Tools' and select 'Options'.

Explore sections like 'Text Editor' and 'Language Services'.

Ensure all settings are correctly configured for Gherkin syntax highlighting.